# Filter results in SQL query for search

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, join

I am trying to write an SQL query to filter records from products table for search depending on the search text.
The text will have multiple words separated by space(e.g. Samsung s6)

The problem is the results should contain all the words in the result.

Now the records can have names like

1. Samsung s6
2. Samsung galaxy s6
3. Samsung A5
4. Samsung galaxy s6 edge
5. Apple Iphone 6

now for search text "samsung s6" should get records 1,2,4 in result but the way i tried is giving me 1,2,3,4 rows in result.

my query is:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempSearch
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.#TempSearch
SELECT * FROM CSVToTable(ISNULL(@ModelName,''),' ')

SELECT 
    T1.*
FROM
    <table1> T1 INNER JOIN #TempSearch T2 ON T1.Name LIKE CONCAT('%', T2.Value, '%')
```

I took the search string in a temp table which contains a row for each word (separated by space)

then inner joined with the main table.

Comment: Please provide the desired result.

Comment: @PM77-1 I have mentioned the desired result in the question "for search text 'samsung s6' i should get records 1,2,4 in result but the way i tried is giving me 1,2,3,4 rows in result from the records in the question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an aggregation and left outer join:

```
SELECT T1.Name
FROM <table1> T1 JOIN
     #TempSearch ts
     ON T1.Name LIKE CONCAT('%', Ts.Value, '%')
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempSearch);
```

This counts the number of matches and makes sure that all components match.
You can add more column to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` to get more columns.

Note:

The following simpler version would work for your example:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.name like '%' + replace(@ModelName, ' ', '%') + '%';
```

Comment: Got it working with your solution i had some spelling mistakes in the search parameter when i tried the first time..
Marked ur ans as solution.. :D